# Remove duplicates in pandas. copy() and drop_duplicates() is removing rows that appear only once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates, data-science

As the question states. I am trying to get rid of duplicate rows in a df with 2 series/columns `df['Offering Family', 'Major Offering']`.

I hope to merge the subsequent df with another one I have based on the Major Offering column, thus only the offering family column will be transposed to the new df. I should note that I only want to get rid of rows with values that are repeated in both columns. If a value appears more than once in the Offering family column but the value in the major offering column is different, it should not be deleted. However, when I run the code below, I'm finding that I'm losing those sorts of values. Can anybody help?

```
df = pd.read_excel(pipelineEx, sheet_name='Data')

dfMO = df[['Offering Family', 'Major Offering']].copy()

dfMO.filter(['Offering Family', 'Major Offering'])

dfMO = df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=False)


#dfMO.drop_duplicates(keep=False,inplace=True)
print(dfMO)

dfMO.to_excel("Major Offering.xlsx")
```

Comment: Can you share a few sample records so we can know what is wrong with the drop_duplicates

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) - we don't have access to your excel file, your [mre] should include data Representative of your real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have upated your code and as Aditya Chhabra mentioned, you are creating a copy and not using it.

```
df = pd.read_excel(pipelineEx, sheet_name='Data')

dfMO = df[['Offering Family', 'Major Offering']].copy()
dfMO.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
print(dfMO)

dfMO.to_excel("Major Offering.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a few things that are odd with the code you've shared.

Primarily, you created a `dfM0` as a copy of `df` with only the two columns. But then you're applying the `drop_duplicates()` function on `df`, the original dataframe, and over-writing the dfM0 you created.

From what I understand, what you need is the dataframe to retain all unique combinations that could be made from values in the two columns. `groupby()` would be better suited for your purposes.

Try this:

```
cols = ['Offering Family', 'Major Offering']
dfM0 = df[cols].groupby(cols).count().reset_index()
```

`reset_index()` will return a copy, by default, so no additional keyword arguments are necessary.

Comment: I liked your approach, although the solution might be a bit advanced for the user.

Comment: @AgyeyArya I suppose the single-line code can be split up for the user's benefit. But I still stand by the `groupby` approach.

Comment: what about just using drop_duplicates(inplace=True) instead. I would like to know why you would prefer group_by.count().reset_index() over the simpler solution. Wouldn't it be more complex ( time and memory wise )